# How can I find out the route to the NavMeshAgent target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

I want to know the route in advance before the hero walks through it, and draw it by means of line Render, tell me if it is possible to find out in any way the route from the agent without letting the body in front of him that he would have already drawn the line, I would be very grateful for any information

In the screenshot, the hero moves through the points using NavMeshAgent, can I find out the route or points to the target

[image]

Comment: Try [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67839/is-there-a-way-to-display-navmesh-agent-path-in-unity).

Comment: Thank you very much this is what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class DisplayedPath : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer line; //to hold the line Renderer
    public Transform target; //to hold the transform of the target
    public NavMeshAgent agent; //to hold the agent of this gameObject

    private void Start()
    {
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>(); //get the line renderer
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>(); //get the agent
                                              //   target = transform;
        StartCoroutine(getPath());
    }

    public IEnumerator getPath()
    {
        // line.SetPosition(0, transform.position); //set the line's origin

        agent.SetDestination(target.position); //create the path
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); //wait for the path to generate

        DrawPath(agent.path);

        agent.Stop();//add this if you don't want to move the agent
    }

    public void DrawPath(NavMeshPath path)
    {
        if (path.corners.Length < 2) //if the path has 1 or no corners, there is no need
            return;

        line.SetVertexCount(path.corners.Length); //set the array of positions to the amount of corners

        line.SetPosition(0, transform.GetChild(0).position); //set the line's origin


        for (var i = 1; i < path.corners.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector3 up = path.corners[i];
            up.y += 1.5f;
            line.SetPosition(i, up); //go through each corner and set that to the line renderer's position
        }
    }
}
```

Thank TEEBQNE.